# How to deal with probability problems in proper class sample spaces?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, reference-request, set-theory, ordinals

Here my focus is mainly on $Ord$ and questions such as:

> - An ordinal is chosen by random. What is the probability of the event that it is a cardinal number?
> - A coin is tossed proper class many times. What is the probability of an event in which the first $\alpha$ tosses have resulted in tail?

In some sense these questions are similar to the following questions which take place in sample spaces $\mathbb{N}$ and $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$ respectively:

> - A natural number is chosen by random. What is the probability of the event that it is a prime number?
> - A coin is tossed (countably) infinite times. What is the probability of an event in which the first $n$ tosses have resulted in tail?

The difficulty is that $Ord$ is a *proper class* and it is not immediately clear what type of object should the $\sigma$-algebra of events be. It seems formalizing the notion of a probability space for a proper class sample space needs some works and stronger axiomatic systems than ZFC.

> **Question:** How to formalize the notion of probability space for proper class sample spaces? Are there any references for development and use of theory of probability for proper class spaces?

Comment: You move to a larger universe and define a filter on the classes of ordinals of the universe. It should naturally assign club classes $1$, which in particular means that choosing a random ordinal it is almost always a limit cardinal which is a fixed point of both $\aleph$ and $\beth$ functions (and in fact the limit of such fixed points and so on and so forth).

Comment: @AsafKaragila Your argument shows that we *expect* the probability of the first question to be $1$ in any formal model of this problem. In this question I'm interested in a way which makes it possible to deal with all types of such questions.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I wonder if we can use Joel's approach in my question [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/141119/how-strong-are-large-cardinal-properties-of-ord) in order to deal with statements like *"$Ord$ is measurable"* in an extension by interpreting it as an statement about the height of a von Neumann hierarchy?

Comment: Well, I'm not quite sure how you'd do that. Since, again, a measure on the ordinals would be a collection of proper classes which might not be an object of the meta-theory (if the meta-theory is some weak arithmetic theory, for example).

Comment: @AsafKaragila This is exactly the difficulty of this *very natural* question. However I think there *is* a natural answer for questions like "*what is the probability of being a successor ordinal if we choose a random ordinal?*" For example Intuitively I think this probability (whatever it means) is greater than $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Ali, I don't know if every difficult question is inherently worth asking. Idle curiosity is fine, but to what end? For what it's worth, I [very] vaguely recall some probabilistic arguments on *countable models* of $\sf ZF$. I think it's a theorem of Sacks, but I don't remember. I'll see if I can find a reference later today.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Thanks in advance for the reference. About this question, in fact I came across it when I was thinking on something else regarding inner models and infinitary games. The theory of probability over proper class sample spaces is much more natural than what it seems!

Comment: [There it is](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1969-142-00/S0002-9947-1969-0253895-6/home.html). And this [MO thread](http://mathoverflow.net/q/121251/7206) might also be of interest (in particular the discussion in the comments).

Answer (score 0):

Under the usual product measure on $2^{ORD}$ (whatever that may mean), the probability that the first $\alpha$ coin tosses be tail is $2^{-|\alpha|}$ which is zero unless $\alpha$ is finite. I cannot make sense of your first question.